# div show / hide

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know of a good example of a div SHOW / HIDE where there is a main DIV and 2-3 other div populate (show/hide) into the Main box? Pretty much what i'm doing is displaying new paragraphs/topic of text.

I understand how to do a standard show/hide with a collapse of a div, but can't seem to find an example of showing divs into a main div

**Edit:**
Maybe I should also add that I need for the links for the show and hide not be nested in the DIV... I have gfx's on the page and the 3 text links are off centered to the right so a traditional tab I don't see working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tabtastic](http://phrogz.net/js/tabtastic/index.html) is still the gold standard for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4):

```
        <input type="radio" name="ValueCost" id="values" checked onclick="javascript:togggleValCost('valueDiv', 'costDiv')" />
     <br> Cost Deduction:

     <input type="radio" name="ValueCost" id="costDeduction" onclick="javascript:togggleValCost('costDiv', 'valueDiv')" />

//javaScript
    function togggleValCost(display, hide){
               document.getElementById(display).style.display = 'block';
               document.getElementById(hide).style.display = 'none';
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) would be a good example matching your need.